# How to check already given class and add another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

recently I wrote one few lines of js in order to check the DOM structure and add "in" class in case user clicked on link. Now I need to use **has** property but I dont know how its used. Here is code:

```
     $(document).on('click', '.collapse-all > a', function () {
     var $collapseList = $(this).closest('#main-content').find('.collapse-list'),
         $container = $collapseList.find('.collapse').removeAttr('style'),
         $collapsed = $collapseList.find('.mehr-pfeil');

     if ($container.filter('.in').length > 0) {
         $container.removeClass('in');
     } else {
         $container.addClass('in');
     }
 });
 $(function () {
     $('.collapse-all > a').click();
 });

// here is my try to check the DOM and add another class on <a> element
 $(function () {
     $container.hasClass('in') {
         if ($container.filter('.in').length > 0) {
             $collapsed.addClass('mehr-pfeil-active');
         } else {
             $collapsed.removeClass('mehr-pfeil-active');
         }
     }
 });
```

So right now everything worked but when I tried to check if js has gave **in** class to .collapse then my code breaks. Can anyone tell me where I've made mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code

1,`$container` is not in the scope of your class checking function.

2, The way you used `hasClass` method is wrong

It will return true or false. So you can check it inside an if condition.

```
var $collapseList = $(this).closest('#main-content').find('.collapse-list');
$container = $collapseList.find('.collapse');
if ($container.hasClass('in')) {
    $collapsed.addClass('mehr-pfeil-active');
} else {
    $collapsed.removeClass('mehr-pfeil-active');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. And thank you for your explanation because I want to learn this!!

Answer (score 2):

[`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) returns a bool so your function may check something like this

```
if($container.hasClass('in')) {
    ...
}
```

---

As noted by [TheBlueAussie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201078/trueblueaussie), your `$container` is also not in the scope of your ready function.

A quick fix would be to global the variable like so

```
var $container;

$(document).on('click', '.collapse-all > a', function () {
    var $collapseList = $(this).closest('#main-content').find('.collapse-list'),
        $collapsed = $collapseList.find('.mehr-pfeil');

    $container = $collapseList.find('.collapse').removeAttr('style');

    ...
}
```

Comment: Murphy's law: *There is always one more problem* - `$container` is also created outside the scope of the function using it.

Comment: Full credit to `Anoop Joshi` for spotting the $container scope issue first. Just bringing it to your attention.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at

**[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)** to check if element has a class.

you can use it in a `if` and than `addClass`

```
if($('.class').hasClass('className'))
{
    $('.class').addClass('xy');
    //or
    $('.class').removeClass('className');
    //and so on
    //.class could be #id as well
}
```

Comment: Murphy's law: *There is always one more problem* - `$container` is also created outside the scope of the function using it.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie and why are you posting this on my post ? i don't even use `$container`. :)

Comment: Why??? Because the question has more than one problem. Just pointing out the one you missed :)

Comment: propably it has more than one... but this is content for a next question :) i didn't missed anything. question was: `How to check already given class and add another one` that's what my answere explains. also see the comment `// here is my try to check...` if i see right... he just TRYS :)

Comment: This is what happens when people don't use JSFiddles etc to test answers. They answer what they think is the problem, when the actual *aim* is to provide a working solution to the entire problem :) Imagine if you told your boss "I just fixed the bug you told me about and ignored the others as you didn't ask". :>

Comment: and even a not acceptet answere can be right. but lets end this discussion. you have your point and i got mine. AND i don't have time for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `hasClass` statement to a condition start since this method returns a boolean (true/false) value:

```
// here is my try to check the DOM and add another class on <a> element
$(function () {
  if ($container.hasClass('in')) {
    if ($container.filter('.in').length > 0) {
      $collapsed.addClass('mehr-pfeil-active');
    } else {
      $collapsed.removeClass('mehr-pfeil-active');
    }
  }
});
```

You should also declare the `$container` variable inside this function or move its initialization to be a global one.

Comment: Murphy's law: *There is always one more problem* - `$container` is also created outside the scope of the function using it.

Comment: Full credit to `Anoop Joshi`. He already has it in his answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I'll use @Annop's code!

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$container.hasClass('in');
```

or if you want to toggle class

```
$container.toggleClass('in')
```

Comment: -1: `hasClass` is pointless without an `if` test added. This is what the OP had already.